# Razor Macro: Divide child nodes into three lists

Tags: asp.net, razor, umbraco

I am making a footer by listing the child-nodes of a specific page with the example included in umbraco 4.11.9 (subs by changable source).

the number of elements in the footer is expected to change, so the macro must divide the list of children and place them as LI's in three UL's.
all children are direct descendants of the source

current code:

```
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContext

@{
    var startNodeID = "1089";
}

@if (startNodeID != null)
{
    @* Get the start node as a dynamic node *@
    var startNode = Library.NodeById(startNodeID);

    if (startNode.Children.Where("Visible").Any())
    {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var page in startNode.Children.Where("Visible"))
            { 
                <li><a href="@page.Url">@page.Name</a></li>
            }
        </ul>
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done something similar before using the modulus operator. See the following example:

```
var col1Count = 1;
var col2Count = 1;
var col3Count = 1;

<div class="col col-3 hide-mobile">
    @foreach (var nodeId in links)
    {
        if (col1Count % 3 == 1)
        {
          // Output column 1 content
        }
        col1Count++;
    }
</div>

<div class="col col-3 hide-mobile">
    @foreach (var nodeId in links)
    {
        if (col2Count % 3 == 2)
        {
          // Output column 2 content
        }
        col2Count++;
    }
</div>

<div class="col col-3 hide-mobile">
    @foreach (var nodeId in links)
    {
        if (col3Count % 3 == 0)
        {
          // Output column 3 content
        }
        col3Count++;
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a somewhat direct approach, but why not try (In your if/.Any()):

Note - This approach uses LINQ

```
    var childNodes = startNode.Children.Where("Visible").ToList();
    int perListCount = childNodes.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
      var activeNodeList = childNodes.Skip(i * perListCount).Take(perListCount);           
      if (i == 2){
        activeNodeList = childNodes.Skip(i * perListCount);
      }
      <ul>
      @foreach(var node in activeNodeList){
      <li><a href="@node.Url">@node.Name</a></li>
      }
      </ul>
    }
```

Comment: ProNotion's example is much better than this one :)